# Check last login date from database and update based on result using SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress, filtering

I need to check a MySQL database for a users last login time and if its within a 30-day time frame, update the users data from say 1 to 0.

Current code is

```
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Get all from last login
$check_last_login = "SELECT * FROM qsnz_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_login'";

$result = $conn->query($check_last_login);

    while($user_last_login = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if(strtotime( $user_last_login["meta_value"] ) < strtotime('1 month ago')) {
           AT THIS POINT I NEED TO DO A SQL INSERT FOR ALL USERS WHO MEET THIS IF STATEMENT  
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

I have got to the point where I do the query and filter results into users who have been online in the last 30 days but then I cant work out how to do a SQL query with the filtered users.

Comment: You can do it using Wordpress funcitons itself then why do you prefer SQL insert over there. You got user_id right. You can use as what i have suggested. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Usage of **Update User meta** will do the trick for you.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

You can update it into the Database with the help of this function.

**Syntax:**

```
<?php update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); ?>
```

Here the **$prev_value** alone **optional** other all are required.

Query:

```
update_user_meta($user_last_login['user_id'],'last_login','0');
```

Comment: So if i wanted to update another row in the database not update the last_login column how would the above need to be altered if for instance the item to be updated was updated_item.

Comment: Yup very easy one. You can use `
<?php add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ); ?>` where the $unique is optional field.

Comment: On the Whole `add_user_meta` adds a New Field to the **usermeta** table and `update_user_meta` will update the current row in the table matching the `meta_key` and `user_id`.

Comment: Have you obtained what i am trying to explain @Dgeorgex000000.

Comment: but what if i needed to do it for every user on the site all at once, so do the query as stated above to find anyone who has been active in the last 30 days and only update the meta for the ones who have?

Comment: You have got the Users `who has been active in the last 30 days` right ?? by  using the code as you have posted to the question...

Comment: but doesnt my original code simply create an array of results form a database query, is it possible to use these results to indentify the users from which they came from?, thanks again for your help btw its really appreciated

Comment: Even though  if it an Array you are using while loop to select it right and as per your condition you are getting users `who has been active in the last 30 days` using the if loop right and inside the if loop you can use `update_user_meta` in order to change the status from `1 to 0` or `0 to 1` as per your requirement.

Comment: If you write your needed query either to `add_user_meta`  or `update_user_meta` it will work fine but you have to pass the `user_id`,`meta_key` and `meta_value` as the required parameters. Hope so your request has been cleared of how to update the `usermeta` table

Comment: do you have email are you interest in freelance work

Comment: Ya i have email as well as interested in freelancer work too.

Comment: please contact me dgeorge1988@hotmail.com and ill get back to you thanks

Comment: @Dgeorgex000000. I have mailed you regarding. Hope so you would be kind enough to do the needful as required. :)

Comment: When i try your suggestion it updates all users , any idea why ?

update_user_meta($user_last_login['user_id'],'last_login','0');

Answer (score 1):

Based on @user3170327's answer, this query gives you the last login timestamp:

```
SELECT wp_users.user_login, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email, wp_users.user_registered, wp_users.user_status, wp_users.display_name, wp_usermeta.meta_value
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wfls-last-login';
```

The output looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| user_login | user_nicename | user_email | user_registered     | user_status | display_name | meta_value |
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| user1      | user1         | user1@mail | 2016-03-21 10:06:51 |           0 | user1        | 1584347697 |
| user2      | user2         | user2@mail | 2016-05-30 12:29:58 |           0 | user2        | 1625661052 |
| user3      | user3         | user3@mail | 2016-06-20 14:47:33 |           0 | user3        | NULL       |
| user4      | user4         | user4@mail | 2016-07-27 10:39:53 |           0 | user4        | 1625583100 |
| user5      | user5         | user5@mail | 2018-02-27 15:03:39 |           0 | user5        | 1626082516 |
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

Then you can convert the column `meta_value` from timestamp to a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subquery, like this: 
**SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);** 
The 'second' select would contain the users who have been online in the last 30 days, and the first 'select' would contain the other query you want to do.

Comment: But how would I get the if(strtotime( $user_last_login["meta_value"] ) < strtotime('1 month ago'))  into the subquery

Answer (score 0):

WordPress DB Print Last Login Date:
Tables: wp_users, wp_usermeta
MySQL Left Join

SELECT wp_users.user_login, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email, wp_users.user_registered, wp_users.user_status, wp_users.display_name, wp_usermeta.meta_value
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = '__ina_last_active_session'

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), and include a bit more information and/or context for why this answers the question. This makes it much more useful for those who come across the same issue later on.