# Is there a way to log or track last login date and last modified date?

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-logging

Is there a way to implement a method to log or track the last WordPress Admin login date and the date when pages were last modified?

I may have looked at the wrong places. I looked through the Apache logs, it doesn't have information of Admin's last login. I can't find any information from Google Cloud Logging and Monitoring too. I can check the last modified date of a stylesheet but the same method is not applicable to theme generated pages.

**Setup**
Bitnami WordPress
Google Cloud Load Balancer
Google CDN
Google Cloud Logging
Google Cloud Monitoring

Comment: You can simply use a premade plugin to show the last modified date. We recommend [WP Last Modified Info](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-last-modified-info). It's free to use and highly rated. Other plugins like [When last login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/when-last-login/) & [Simple History](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-history/) etc... Also you can also code to your theme's functions.php file. Refer to [OptinMonster](https://optinmonster.com/how-to-display-change-last-modified-wordpress/) for more details.

Comment: You can use the audit and investigation page to run searches related to [User log events](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580120?product_name=UnuFlow\&hl=en\&visit_id=638041275540255003-484136249\&rd=1\&src=supportwidget0\&hl=en).

Comment: WordPress does not log that information which means Cloud Logging will not help you. This Q&A will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39192511/8016720 with the first part of your question. The `wp_posts` table includes details on each post revision. You would need to query that table. The last update time, user, etc is recorded. This link has details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts